# Does automatic feature selection for clustering helps with finding meaningful clusters?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, feature-selection, unsupervised-learning

The objective of clustering is to find interesting groups in data. My question is, whether feature selection can substantially help with this objective.

I understand feature selection can remove redundant variables, which might help with interpretation. However, the feature selection finds a subset by optimizing for *compactness/separation*. Thus, it might find a subset, which has a higher compactness/separation but actually has lower association with the concept I am looking for.

Doesn't make more sense to manually select the features, because it is, in fact, defining the task I am interested in?

---

More clarification: In supervised learning there is a label, that defines a task. Then, I can remove features or do anything else, as long as it predicts the label. In clustering, on the other hand, the definition of a task are the unlabeled data itself. Thus, by changing the data (feature selection) I am changing the task and might searching  for something not meaningful.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. First of all feature selection is *not* about removing correlated features. Blindly removing correlated features may be a very bad idea in many cases. Second, feature selection is usually used for supervised algorithms, not unsupervised. Third, if you can select features manually based on some kind expert knowledge, you wouldn't use automated solutions.

Comment: The objective of clustering is to find interesting groups in data. My question is, whether feature selection can substantially help with this goal.

1) Not sure about if the "correlated" part is precise, but for sure, one of the goals with feature selection for clustering is to remove redundant features. [1]

Comment: 2) Yeah, but there are many methods for clustering too (e.g. [1]), thus I am asking about those methods.
3) Not necessary. It is possible you might select features based on expert knowledge and do the feature selection afterward to improve the clustering (again, it is core of my question).

[1] https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11222-016-9670-1

Answer (score 1):

The objective of clustering is *given the data* to group it into several groups. If you change the data, the results also could change. There is no feature selection methods for cluster analysis because the point of cluster analysis is to find groups *in the data you have*. It is your decision what kind of data you want to use to find the groups.

For example, you could have a data on patients from some hospital. You could cluster this data based on many different features. It is a completely different problem if you group those patients by demographics, as compared to grouping them based on their medical conditions. Surely, there may be overlap and the overlap may be interesting by itself, but those are answering two different research questions.

Comment: Actually, there are at least several methods. For example link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11222-016-9670-1

Comment: Free access link: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271447963_Variable_selection_for_model-based_clustering_using_the_integrated_complete-data_likelihood

Comment: @sitnarf I didn’t read the paper, but it seems to describe regularization, so this is slightly different problem and solution.